# AWS IoT Device Onboarding

Tags: amazon-web-services, arduino, iot, esp32

I'm working on a learning project for IoT with AWS IoT Things and ESP32 using Arduino/C (no micro-python). While I have shadows and messages working well, the part I'm not sure about is the best approach to onboard new devices.

Currently the onboarding process is:

1. I create the Thing in the AWS Console
2. I create the certs
3. I save the certs to laptop
4. I copy cert contents into the Shadow.h then upload the sketch to the ESP32

This feels incredibly manual :(

Hypothetically how would a reseller of ESP32-based IoT devices automate the onboarding process? How can the Things and certs be automated?

Many thanks in advance

Ant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're talking about provisioning devices in cloud.

If you (or your organization) is adding your own devices to your own cloud, then it's quite easy to automate. Steps 1 and 2 are the cloud-side part of provisioning - just install the required SDK-s and write a script in your favourite supported scripting language to do the dirty work. For steps 3 and 4 you just use the device's own Flash to store the device certificates. Espressif has a useful non-volatile storage system called [NVS](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/storage/nvs_flash.html) - it's fairly easy to use and supports Flash encryption (this bit could be more elegant, but it works). You can use their [NVS Partition Generator](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/storage/nvs_partition_gen.html) to pre-create the required storage with the device's certs in it, then flash it into the device when setting it up. Device-side provisioning can be scripted together with cloud-side provisioning so you can do the whole thing in a single step. The Arduino IDE is not the tool to use, though. You just need the final program binaries, but everything else you need to create on your own.

If you're talking about a third party taking your device and provisioning it in *their* cloud, this is a bit more difficult (but not impossible). Presumably they need to do steps 1 & 2 on their own and you need to give them a way to configure their AWS endpoints and certificates on the device. So you need to build some interface which allows them to do it.

Comment: Hi Tarmo, thanks so much for your explanation!

If I'm understanding this correctly, the application itself would be uploaded sans certs, the certs AWS generate would be downloaded by the script and then would be uploaded to flash/NVS through the partition generator utility.

Yes I did mean that these devices were to be used in my own platform but purchased by third-parties. Such as providing access control or agriculture sensing solutions and my platform could be the 'hub'. At this point just a learning excercise on how the devices 'should' be provisioned in a more automated process.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. The device firmware and the device attributes (e.g. certificates, serial number, etc) are two different things. Attributes should not be hardcoded into the firmware (firmware is one generic blob of code which works on all devices and can be upgraded en masse). If you're selling to other people devices which all connect to your cloud solution using your certificates, it's much easier to manage. There are caveats. Your cloud is the biggest and most fragile single point of failure and some people will not accept that kind of loss of control in a commercial solution.